Calculating the correct exit points and position size for strategy
I want to create a strategy that enters at certain conditions and calculates the stop loss and position size based on the factor, target and entrypoint.
The practical example should look like this:
example on chart
So basically:

The strategy should enter a long as soon as a candle closes back inside the value range
Target of that move is known (Target name: VAHTarget)
Entry of that trade is known
Now based on the Long Tool from tradingview, i want to enter a trade, that has a 1.5 factor and want to calculate automatically the position size and stop loss so in the end the factor is 1.5.

How can i do that?
My code i have currently is:
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

// Exit conditions for long positions
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    if (strategy.position_avg_price < pd_poc)
        strategy.exit("Partial Profit Long", "Long", limit=pd_poc, qty_percent=50)
    if (strategy.position_avg_price < pd_vah)
        strategy.exit("Take Profit Long", "Long", limit=pd_vah)

I tried different approaches but in the end nothing rly gave me the result i wanted.
